# outputting the row with a maximum field in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, max, aggregate

This is a part of a table of data that I have:

[image]

how can I query this table to return for each city, only the row with MAX(turnover), for example for `Berlin` only the row that has `21.574,00` should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Postgres, you should use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (city) city, store, dow, turnover
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY city, turnover DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

to generate `max(turnover)` for each `city`, use `group by`.

```
select city, max(turnover) turnover
from tableA
group by city
```

Comment: This doesn't give you the other columns though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT city, max(turnover) FROM table GROUP BY city` this will return city and its maximum turnover

Answer (score 0):

if you need all columns where the max value is reached you may use windowed functions like this...

```
with your_fake_table as (
select * from (
values (1, 'Berlin' , 1 , 21000),
(1, 'Berlin' , 2 , 10000),
(1, 'Berlin' , 3 , 5000),
(2, 'Essen' , 31 , 10000),
(2, 'Essen' , 5 , 11000)
) as V (store, city, down, turnover))

select store, city, down, turnover
from (
select 
store,
city,
FIRST_VALUE(down) over (partition by city order by turnover desc) as down,
max(turnover) over (partition by city) as turnover
from your_fake_table
)V
group by store, city, down, turnover
```

but if you dont need the down column, need only the city /store/ max turnover
a simple grouping would be better for you

```
select store, city, max(turnover) turnover
from your_table
group by store, city
```

see the fiddle with demo with the samples:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e61b775321b4120d87ea11626c09c140